# how to code handlebars helper with ember and require.js

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

```
define([ "handlebars","ember"], function(Handlebars,Ember) {
  Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('judgeStatus', function(value) {
    alert(value);
    var result = value;
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
  });
});
```

`Uncaught [object Object] handlebars.js:706 verifyMatch`

need Handlebars Helper when i use `require.js` how to code it?

Answer (score 1):

like this...

```
define(["ember",], function(Ember) {
    Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('judgeStatus', function(value) {
      var result = '';      
      return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(result);
    });
});
```